# Google Cloud Storage issue with PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I am using this library: `google/cloud-storage`.

In my storage I made a bucket, called: `mycustombucket`. My goal is to upload a csv file in that bucket.
Here is my code:

```
  $storage = new StorageClient([
     'projectId' => 'my project id',
     'keyFile' => json_decode('{
       "web":{
          "client_id":"my client id",
          "project_id":"my project id",
          "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
          "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
          "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"my auth value",
          "client_secret":"my client secret"
       }
      }', true)
  ]);
  $bucket = $storage->bucket('mycustombucket');
  $bucket->upload(
           fopen('path/to/my/file.csv', 'r')
  );
```

Unfortunately, I got this error message: `json key is missing the type field` . I found this similar [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46828610/json-key-is-missing-the-type-field), but it doesn't work for me. I think it is also outdated.

The content of the JSON, I downloaded it from here:
[image]

Would you please suggest me and idea, how to fix this ?

Thank you!

Comment: Is that the full and complete error message?

Comment: You are missing some closing bits `]);`. Surely your IDE is showing the missing part of that to you

Comment: yes :(  That message is thrown by the exception from : `\Google\Auth\CredentialsLoader::makeCredentials`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I 've updated my post with missing closing bits. :)

Comment: I don't know why this question is closed. I said in my post that there is a similar one and the answer from there doesn't work for me. PLUS, I think it is outdated!

Comment: I closed it because the code had a HUGE Syntax error in it!! Please take a little more care when posting your question. ___We can only judge what we see___

Comment: @RiggsFolly I already updated it :)  Srry for the wrong copy paste :)

Comment: I know you did, I repoened the question when you did that

Comment: Looks like it is expecting something like `"type": "service_account",` in the json. Maybe double check you copy/pasted correctly or try adding that to your json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I managed to get this work, by generating a key from the `service account`. From:
[image]

Please not that once you generated you will automatically download it. A download button will not be available anymore. So make sure you have the key after generated it. I would expect to have a download button for the `service account`, like I have for `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs` (see my post). But I don't :(.
Finally my code:

```
    $storage = new StorageClient([
        'projectId' => 'projectId' => 'my project id',
        'keyFile' => json_decode('{
              "type": "service_account",
              "project_id": "my project id",
              "private_key_id": "my key id",
              "private_key": "my key",
              "client_email": "email@email.com",
              "client_id": "client id",
              "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
              "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
              "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
              "client_x509_cert_url": "url here"
        }', true)
    ]);
```